# Detecting Arrays when accessing Document Elements by Position

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, dom

```
As the browser reads an HTML document and forms a parse tree, JavaScript objects are 
instantiated for all elements that are scriptable. Initially, the number of markup 
elements that were scriptable in browsers was limited, but with a modern browser it 
is possible to access any arbitrary HTML element.
```

However, for now, being a novice to Scripting languages, I am concentrating on the ***HTML elements*** accessible via the ***traditional JavaScript object model*** (also known as ***DOM Level 0***), particularly  and ***its related elements***, to keep things simple.

***Detecting Arrays***
        While ***arrays*** aren’t that different than *objects*, we may treat them as such, and detecting for them may be important. Unfortunately, `typeof` won’t be much help.

```
    var arr = [];
    alert(typeof arr);            // "object"

    alert(arr instanceof Array);  // returns true

    alert(Array.isArray(arr));    // returns true
```

Using the `traditional JavaScript object model`, we can access the `<form>` tags using

```
window.document.forms
```

which is a collection that looks like an array in a basic sense.
***Considering a  very basic form***

```
    <form action="form1action.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="field1">

    </form>
    <br><br>

    <form action="form2action.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="field2">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="field3">

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        console.log(typeof window.document.forms[1].elements[1]);            // object
        console.log(typeof window.document.forms[1].elements);               // object
        console.log(window.document.forms[1].elements instanceof Array);     // false
        console.log(window.document.forms instanceof Array);  // false

    </script>
```

I find myself really confused with the unexpected behavior(which is only for me)

```
console.log(window.document.forms[1].elements instanceof Array);  // false
console.log(typeof window.document.forms instanceof Array);       // false
```

as I have an impression that the JavaScript engine will treat ***something[]*** as an ***instanceof*** ***Array***, in above case is focussing on `elements and forms`.

Comment: I found your question a bit confusing, but you *seem* to be saying that if the square brackets `[]` can be used with an object it must be an array? That's not the case. Square bracket syntax can be used to access the properties of any object. In your example `forms` is an array-like object, but not actually an array.

Comment: @nnnnnnn: No, I know very well that document["write"], doesn't makes document to behave like an Array. I said , my case is focussing elements and forms.

Comment: Well as I said, `forms` is an array-like object, not an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn: thanks for extending a helping hand. Once again thank you, indeed!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not everything with indexed properties (`[0], [1]` etc) is an Array - it can be any sort of a collection of objects, which is not the same thing. It may even just be an object with a `0` property and not a collection at all.

In this scenario, `document.forms` is an `HTMLCollection` - a specialised collection of HTML elements - and `window.document.forms[1].elements` is a  `HTMLFormControlsCollection`, which inherits from `HTMLCollection`.

```js
// all log true
console.log(window.document.forms instanceof HTMLCollection);
console.log(window.document.forms[1].elements instanceof HTMLFormControlsCollection);
console.log(window.document.forms[1].elements instanceof HTMLCollection);

// NOTE: typeof doesn't give the exact type of an object.
// This just logs "object", rather than "HTMLCollection", because it is an object, as opposed to e.g. a number
console.log(typeof window.document.forms);

var myObject = {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
// log "foo bar"
console.log(myObject[0], myObject[1]);
```

```html
<form></form>
<form></form>
```

Mozilla's documentation on MDN is often useful for seeing the actual type of an object, e.g. [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms) and [`HTMLFormElement.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements).